How to remove uninstalled apps from Family Link permanently?
The lists of apps in Family Link on my children's devices are getting longer and longer. Many apps are pre-installed apps from the manufacturer that were available on former devices but are not available in the Play Store. Others are apps from kindergarten and would never be installed again.
Is there a way to remove apps from the app list in Google's Family Link?
